# Ec2 AutoScaling User Data not running

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to add `user data` to my auto scaling on AWS.

When I setup my launch configuration through the web console on AWS I entered the following user data:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $RANDOM > /home/ubuntu/clusterID
```

I had to base64 encode it, I did that with base64encode.org. The result:

```
IyEvYmluL2Jhc2gNCmVjaG8gJFJBTkRPTSA+IC9ob21lL3VidW50dS9jbHVzdGVySUQ=
```

When the ec2 instance launches I see the following error:

> 2015-02-24 07:50:08,754 - **init**.py[WARNING]: Unhandled
>   non-multipart userdata starting 'IyEvYmluL2Jhc2gNCmVjaG8g...'

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Is your /home or /home/ubuntu a separate partition? If yes, you can check if the fs is mounted properly before the command executes.

I faced similar kind of issue 1.5 year back and it was the same mistake I mentioned....

Comment: How would I do that? Not sure I follow :)

Answer (score 0):

ok..

seems the data passed in user-data does not have to be encoded(base64).

You can pass the user-data as it is and aws cli will pass this data to ec2 instance after encoding.